# Construction of roots

Tags: geometric-construction

Is there elementary proof that,  for example, $\sqrt[3]2$, cannot be constructed using rule and compass?

Also, my guess is that only roots which are powers of $2$ (2nd root, 4th root, 8th root, etc.) can be geometrically constructed, is this true?

Please, do not use higher mathematics such as Galois theory because I have only 1st year university math knowledge.

Comment: Your guess is right, but I doubt that there is a proof using nothing from Galois theory.

Comment: Oh, nice (guess). Can you recommend some literature for learning Galois theory for beginners?

Comment: There is a reason it took until the 19th century to prove you can't double the cube. If there were a more elementary proof, chances are high the ancient Greeks, or any of a number of really clever mathematicians who attempted a proof in the meantime, would've found it.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks. Honestly, I did not search any history of this problems, just the proof.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53648/589

Comment: Look at this book - https://indianaeducations.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/famous-problems-of-geometry-how-to-solve-them-benjamin-bold.pdf